# Use set() in Alarm Manager with values i have

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, alarm

How do i use the two vales i have (hour and minute ) to set and alarm at that time? The values i have unfortuntly arent formated so if hour is > 12 it wont go to one (Its in milatary time format) .Did i set up the pending intent correctly?

```
public void setUpAlarm(int hour,int minute) {

    long newTime;

    Intent alarm = Intent(setAlarmList.this, AlarmReciever.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent waiting = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(setAlarmList.this, 0, alarm, 0);
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, hour.);
```

Answer (score 0):

**use below code**

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h); // h->hour in 24 hrs system
                    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, m); // m->minutes

Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

                    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>16)
                    {
                        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), broadcast);
                    }else
                    {
                        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
                    }   //alarmIntent is your PendingIntent
```

read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) documentation